# clojure spec, keyword should be nilable

Tags: clojure

I have a simple problem.
Given a spec def, I want to use the same spec but only as a nilable variant.

E.g.

```
(s/def ::uuid uuid?)
(s/def ::problem-spec (s/keys :req-un [::uuid]))
(s/def ::nilable-problem-spec (s/keys :req-un [::uuid])) ; <- (or nil ::uuid)

; what I expect
(s/valid? ::uuid #uuid "9494a3e0-7ef0-4b3f-b539-bd7f7f4f0181") ; true
(s/valid? ::uuid nil) ; false
(s/valid? ::problem-spec {:uuid #uuid "9494a3e0-7ef0-4b3f-b539-bd7f7f4f0181"}) ; true
(s/valid? ::problem-spec {:uuid nil}) ; false
(s/valid? ::nilable-problem-spec {:uuid #uuid "9494a3e0-7ef0-4b3f-b539-bd7f7f4f0181"}) ; true
(s/valid? ::nilable-problem-spec {:uuid nil}) ; true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've defined `::uuid` as non-nillable you cannot then use the `::uuid` key for a nilable value in a map/keyset. This is intentional - qualified keys in spec are globally defined.

What you can do in this case is to spec `::uuid` as nillable and then restrict the non-nillable version of the key set:

```
(s/def ::uuid (s/nilable uuid?))

(s/def ::problem-spec (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::uuid])
                             #(some? (:uuid %))))

(s/def ::nilable-problem-spec (s/keys :req-un [::uuid])) ;; as previously
```

Alternatively, since you're dealing with unqualified keys in the maps you can also define two different qualified `uuid` keywords with different semantics:

```
(s/def :nillable/uuid (s/nilable uuid?))
(s/def :non.nil/uuid uuid?)

(s/def ::problem-spec (s/keys :req-un [:non.nil/uuid])))
(s/def ::nilable-problem-spec (s/keys :req-un [:nillable/uuid]))
```